# How to call a function from a separate script and said script activates on multiple gameobjects?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have this dungeon generation and am trying to call a function to generate rooms on the outside of the dungeon so the player cant walk into nothing-ness. I just need to be able to activate this [Raycast check](https://pastebin.com/Mi9bte08)  from the main dungeon generation and have it activate on all the gameobject(different room types) that have been created.

Here is my main code for the dungeon :

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Dungeon : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int dungeonRoomsCount = 0;
    public int MaxDungeonRoomCount = 0;
    int roomiD = 0;

    Vector2 RoomPos = new Vector2(0, 0);
    public GameObject Room1_4x4;
    public GameObject Room2_3x3Up;
    public GameObject Room0_4x4;

    public DungeonRaycastCheck RayCheck;

    int roomDirection;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startTile();

        for (; dungeonRoomsCount < MaxDungeonRoomCount ; dungeonRoomsCount++ )
        {

            roomDirection = Random.Range(0, 4);
            if (roomDirection == 0)
            {
                dungeonUp();
            }
            else if (roomDirection == 1)
            {
                dungeonDown();
            }
            else if (roomDirection == 2)
            {
                dungeonLeft();
            }
            else if (roomDirection == 3)
            {
                dungeonRight();
            }

        }
        print("done Generation");


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void startTile()
    {
       dungeonRoomsCount = dungeonRoomsCount + 1;
       Instantiate(Room0_4x4, new Vector2(RoomPos.x, RoomPos.y), Quaternion.identity);

     }

    public void dungeonUp()
    {
        roomiD = Random.Range(0, 2);
        print("Room-Up");
        if (roomiD == 0)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2(RoomPos.x, (RoomPos.y = RoomPos.y + 10)), Quaternion.identity);


        }


        else if (roomiD == 1)
        {

            Instantiate(Room2_3x3Up, new Vector2(RoomPos.x, (RoomPos.y = RoomPos.y + 10)), Quaternion.identity);


        }

    }

    public void dungeonDown()
    {
        roomiD = Random.Range(0, 2);
        print("Room-Down");
        if (roomiD == 0)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2(RoomPos.x, (RoomPos.y = RoomPos.y - 10)), Quaternion.identity);


        }


        else if (roomiD == 1)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2(RoomPos.x, (RoomPos.y = RoomPos.y - 10)), Quaternion.identity);


        }

    }

    public void dungeonLeft()
    {
        roomiD = Random.Range(0, 2);
        print("Room-Left");
        if (roomiD == 0)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2((RoomPos.x = RoomPos.x + 10), RoomPos.y), Quaternion.identity);


        }


        else if (roomiD == 1)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2((RoomPos.x = RoomPos.x + 10), RoomPos.y), Quaternion.identity);


        }

    }

    public void dungeonRight()
    {
        roomiD = Random.Range(0, 2);
        print("Room-Right");
        if (roomiD == 0)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2((RoomPos.x = RoomPos.x - 10), RoomPos.y), Quaternion.identity);


        }


        else if (roomiD == 1)
        {

            Instantiate(Room1_4x4, new Vector2((RoomPos.x = RoomPos.x - 10), RoomPos.y), Quaternion.identity);


        }

    }

}
```

Basically i just want to activate the raycheck function from my dungeonraycheck script on all the gameobjects but im not sure how too?

help would be appropriated as well as ways i can improve my code!

Comment: hi! i see no concrete answer in your question please add a sentence with a question mark ;)

Comment: You should probably have an internal model of the dungeon (a 2D array of things) rather than using the scene objects alone.  You generate your dungeon internally and then create the rooms/walls/whatever within the scene based on this internal model.

Answer (score 0):

If the script which the method is in had a static instance you could do RAYCAST_SCRIPT.instance.RaycastCheck();

I'll call the raycast class RayCastScript

to add that go to the RayCastScript class and add the variable
public static RayCastScript instance;

then put this in the start method:

void Start() {

instance = this;

}

then whenever you want to use that function you can just run RayCastScript.instance.RaycastCheck();

Comment: i did that, here is my raycast check https://pastebin.com/ws59VgFb and my dungeon https://pastebin.com/yzx89WTf but im getting the error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Dungeon.Start () (at Assets/Scenes/Dungeon.cs:47). I dont have a raycast check attached to my master is that the problem?